# Migrating Reports From Cognos8 to SSRS Report Builder 3

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, cognos-8

My company is beginning to migrate from Cognos8 to Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3, and we have some very complex reports within Cognos8 that need to move across.

I have seen mentioned online that using the XML from the Cognos8 report, you can import that into Report Builder 3 to replicate the report, however nowhere mentions where to do it? Has anyone had experience with this?

Is it possible to migrate a report from one system to the other, using the XML or the SQL for instance? The underlying database that is being read is the same.

This article [Here](https://www.nousinfosystems.com/portals/_default/skins/Corporate/pdf/WhitePapers/cognos-to-ssrs-migration-brief-overview.pdf) seems to mention it being possible, Page 5 of 8:

"The Cognos report needs to be in XML 
format for the report to be converted to 
an  SSRS  report.  Open  a  Cognos  report
via  IBM  Cognos  Report  Studio,  go  to
Tools menu and select “Show Specification”.
From  here,  one  can  get  the  XML
equivalent of the Cognos report.

Data  can  be  retrieved  from  XML  data
sources      directly      with      Reporting
Services using the XML data provider. It 
converts  XML  structure  into  a  data  set
and SSRS utilizes the same to generate 
reports."

Comment: No you can't use the XML from a Cognos 8 report to convert to a SSRS report. They are completely different. You'll need to redevelop them all

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ah ok thanks very much. Thats a massive shame, as I dont seem to get along as well with SSRS compared to Cognos8. Strange a few websites and articles mention it being possible, but maybe I was misunderstanding.

Comment: Both report definitions are tree structured but there’s no way you’d be able to map between them. Also SSRS generally requires direct SQL whereas Cognos does not. You should put some links to these articles in your question

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have added in a link to an article I saw mentioning its possibility. Both sit on top of the same database, and I can access the Cognos SQL that would run against that database, if that helps SSRS understand?

Comment: TBH that linked PDF is all over the place and very light in detail. They‘ve completely mixed up the concept of xml report definition and XMK data sources which have nothing to do with each other

Comment: If the reports are that old (Cognos 8) then you’re better off rewriting from scratch. Don’t forget to cull the report catalog because often many reports are no longer used.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the heads up. I will start to rebuild from scratch. Theres only two main reports that I was looking at this method for as they are very complex and will take some work to transfer across. The only reason its coming from Cognos8 is because thats the reporting solution that came with the software we are upgrading.

Comment: The quote you pulled from that PDF pulls together totally unrelated information supposedly from web sites that don't even exist. (http://www.bimonkey.com and http://beyondrelational.com from the references at the end of the document have the most likely titles to source that quote.)  Jayaprakash must be in the creative writing division of Nous Infosystems.  He's certainly not in IT.

Comment: @dougp I completely agree - that PDF is a glossy load of rubbish.

Comment: In fact you could probably _could_ write a Cognos (XML) > SSRS (RDL) report converter but it would only work for a very trivial Cognos report and would not include formatting. You definitely won't be able to do it for a complex report. SSRS doesn't have the data model concept that Cognos does which is kind of a good thing because you can write optimised SQL instead of hoping the Cognos DAL gets it right. It's actually a good opportunity to rewrite a report.